# how to give current directory path in xml file

Tags: java, html, xml, spring, xslt

I have created a project. and created folder hierarchy like xml->conf->font

In conf folder i have put my XCONF file and in font folder i have put my fonts(ttf files)

Now i want to give reference to fonts in XCONF file. Please provide me solution:
My XCONF file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fop>
<renderers>
<renderer mime="application/pdf">
 <fonts>
 <directory>/font</directory>
 <directory recursive="true">/font</directory>
   <auto-detect/>
    <font embed-url="/font/grotesque-mt-1361500685.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="GrotesqueMT" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    </font>

    <font embed-url="/font/grotesquemt-light.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="GrotesqueMT-Light" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>

  <font embed-url="/font/grotesquemt-bold.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="GrotesqueMT-Bold" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
  </font>


 </fonts>
</renderer>
```

I am getting following exception:
Failed to resolve font with embed-url '/font/grotesque-mt-1361500685.ttf

Answer (score 2):

you may try `embed-url="./font/...ttf"` or `embed-url="font/...ttf"`. The leading / normaly identifies an absolut URL. Your url point to an font directory on the root of your filesystem.

best regards Majo